# Images from fisheye camera are displayed correctly with BGR8 encoding but not with MONO8

Tags: ros, opencv, ros-kinetic, camera, camera-info

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I want to output grayscale images from a fisheye camera (FOV < 180 degree). I understand that ROS currently doesn't support fisheye [distortion models](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/sensor_msgs/html/namespacesensor__msgs_1_1distortion__models.html). However, I see that if I use a BGR8 image encoding (by setting sensor_msgs::image_encodings::BGR8), I can still get a "normal" distorted image, like this:
[image: normal_BGR8].

But if I change to MONO8 encodings, the image is unusable:
[image: weird_MONO8]

These 2 images were captured with my camera firmly attached to the table.
So I don't understand why I can get a "normal" color image but not a grayscale one?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289324/images-from-fisheye-camera-are-displayed-correctly-with-bgr8-encoding-but-not-with-mono8/) by [tuandl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28760/tuandl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 358 on 2018-04-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi There,

The problem here is that the encoding you are setting doesn't actually control the image content it only describes what's there. In the case of your first image it is being stored in 8 bit BGR encoding so with that specified it looks as it should.

In the case of the second image you've set the encoding to Mono 8 but the data of the image hasn't changed, as a result we are only seeing the leftmost third of the image. In this image each horizontal group of 3 grey pixels intensities are representing the blue, green and red components of the original image.

It's possible that the camera node you're using cannot produce grey scale images directly. In that case you can make a simple node that receives color images converts them to grey scale using OpenCV and publishes them again.

I have worked with wide and fish-eye lenses quite a bit in ROS, I use the [OpenCV fish-eye](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/db/d58/group__calib3d__fisheye.html) functions directly.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tuandl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28760/tuandl/) on 2018-04-22**:
@PeterBlackerThe3rd: you are correct. I figured out that my camera needs to be set in gray_scale_mode to output grayscale images, otherwise, it will output color. Thanks for your clarification!

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-04-22**:
No problem, glad you got it working.